# Python Importing files from other folders (within the same project)?

Tags: python, import, directory

New to python and not understanding how imports work. I saw something about how you can do a sys.path.append but I don't want to do this because this needs to go into source control and run off multiple different computers with different pathing. How do I simply import a file that is in another folder but within the same project?

My file structure is

```
- Project

  - FolderA
    - FileA.py

  - FolderB
    - SubfolderB
      - FileB.py
```

How do I import FileA.py while inside FileB.py?

This doesn't work because I get back 'No Module named FolderA':

```
from FolderA import FileA

class FileB():
...
```

Comment: create a ` __init__.py ` file in each folder and then import function from there like `from foldera import func1`

Answer (score 0):

Add `__init__.py` to each directory to turn them into packages.  Then you can use relative imports, such as in fileb.py

```
from ..FolderA import FileA
```

See [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/8357969) for detailed explanation of relative imports and how they work in python.

Comment: When I do this now I get an error saying 'exceptions.Value Error, Attempted relative import in non-package'

Comment: Are you executin FileB.py from within FolderB?

Comment: I am using visual studio code and just debugging the test with the FileB.py selected.

Comment: See my updated answer for how relative imports work.

Answer (score 0):

Make your subfolders python [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Make sure that only the root is on the python path.

Even better use a standard layout and use pip -e installs

See [this](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/) for a great layout.

Then use absolute imports like import package.subpackage.module or explicit relative ones like import .module